# Trying to do some jquery code after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have some links and I want something to happen when I click on the link. However, I’m creating these elements with .append
This is my jQuery code :

```
$(".ClickTools").click(function(){alert(1);});
```

It doesn’t work after the .append, but it does work when the element is there already (without using append). I need this code to work even when the element has been added to the page with append

This is html code:

```
<div id="appender"></div>
```

And this is my jQuery append code:

```
$("#appender).append('<a class=".ClickTools">click on me</a>');
```

When I click on the `Click on me` button, nothing happens. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the dom-element is not existent on parsing, you have to bind event to an element that´s already there, e.g document:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ClickTools',function(){ console.log(123) });
```

Also you dont need the dot (.) while appending and setting classname (fixed also the missing quote )

```
$("#appender").append('<a class="ClickTools">click on me</a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way :

```
$('<a>click on me</a>').appendTo('#appender').click(function(){alert(1);});
```

Using appendTo will allow your created object to be returned last, so you can directly add a click event to it.